Using IF THEN function to calculate a rolling number in a dataframe
I am in need of help trying to create a calculated metric.  I am trying to create an RSI calculation for a stock dataset.  To do so I want to look at the last 14 days and find the average gain for all days where the stock price was up.  I then will have to do the same for all days the stock market is down.
Here is an example table:
example tabe of data i expect
 I am doing these calculations across multiple stocks, so I created a dictionary which I then concatenate.  Here is the code:

stocklist=["^SPX", "^DJI"]
d={}
def averageGain14(dailyGain):
    if dailyGain>= 0:
        gain = dailyGain
    return gain
for name in stocklist:
    d[name]= pd.DataFrame()
    data = yf.Ticker(name)
    data = data.history(start=myStart, end=myEnd)
    d[name]= pd.DataFrame(data)
    d[name]["Daily Gain"]=d[name]["Close"].diff()
    d[name]['Average Gain'] = d[name]["Daily Gain"].apply(averageGain14)
    d[name] = d[name].add_prefix(name)
modelData = pd.concat(d.values(), axis=1)

As you can see, I try to define a function for averagegain14 at the top, which is not currently doing anything yet but returning the gain value if the day was up (step 1 of getting this working).  In the For loop, I am trying to set the "Average Gain" Column to a calculated field that applies the function to the "Daily Gain" column, but I seem to be running into an error.
I tried a few approaches, but to no avail.  First I tried
d[name]['Average Gain'] = d[name].rolling(14).mean().where(d[name]['Daily Gain'] >= 0, 0)
That returned an error regarding the Daily Gain value being a list and not a single value.  I then tried appending the daily gain call with .values, but that didn't work either.  I then tried this approach above that is not working.   I think to add complexity, I need this to also be a rolling average based on the last 14 days, so to not only calculate add up the positive days, but to also then find the average gain for those days (know the denominator of how many days were up in the 14 day window).   Hopefully this is making sense and someone can point me in the right direction.

Your question is missing a [mre] of data and the matching expected output

Thanks Mozway, updated with a table for an example

Please read the above link again, an image is not reproducible (and you haven't provided the matching expected output) ;)

As was pointed out bu @mozway, it is necessary for you to add a reproducible: Here is an alternative approach to the previously proposed solution:
 import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

stocklist = ["^SPX", "^DJI"]

def calculate_rsi(data, window=14):
    delta = data['Close'].diff()  
    gain = delta.where(delta > 0, 0)  
    loss = -delta.where(delta < 0, 0)  
    
    avg_gain = gain.rolling(window=window).mean()  
    avg_loss = loss.rolling(window=window).mean()  
    
    rs = avg_gain / avg_loss  
    rsi = 100 - (100 / (1 + rs))  
    
    return rsi

myStart = '2022-01-01'
myEnd = '2023-01-01'


d = {}

for name in stocklist:
    data = yf.Ticker(name).history(start=myStart, end=myEnd)
    data['RSI'] = calculate_rsi(data)
    d[name] = data.add_prefix(name + '_')

modelData = pd.concat(d.values(), axis=1)

print(modelData)

which gives you
                             ^SPX_Open    ^SPX_High     ^SPX_Low   ^SPX_Close  \
Date                                                                            
2022-01-03 00:00:00-05:00  4778.140137  4796.640137  4758.169922  4796.560059   
2022-01-04 00:00:00-05:00  4804.509766  4818.620117  4774.270020  4793.540039   
2022-01-05 00:00:00-05:00  4787.990234  4797.700195  4699.439941  4700.580078   
2022-01-06 00:00:00-05:00  4693.390137  4725.009766  4671.259766  4696.049805   
2022-01-07 00:00:00-05:00  4697.660156  4707.950195  4662.740234  4677.029785   
...                                ...          ...          ...          ...   
2022-12-23 00:00:00-05:00  3815.110107  3845.800049  3797.010010  3844.820068   
2022-12-27 00:00:00-05:00  3843.340088  3846.649902  3813.219971  3829.250000   
2022-12-28 00:00:00-05:00  3829.560059  3848.320068  3780.780029  3783.219971   
2022-12-29 00:00:00-05:00  3805.449951  3858.189941  3805.449951  3849.280029   
2022-12-30 00:00:00-05:00  3829.060059  3839.850098  3800.340088  3839.500000   

                           ^SPX_Volume  ^SPX_Dividends  ^SPX_Stock Splits  \
Date                                                                        
2022-01-03 00:00:00-05:00   3831020000             0.0                0.0   
2022-01-04 00:00:00-05:00   4683170000             0.0                0.0   
2022-01-05 00:00:00-05:00   4887960000             0.0                0.0   
2022-01-06 00:00:00-05:00   4295280000             0.0                0.0   
2022-01-07 00:00:00-05:00   4181510000             0.0                0.0   
...                                ...             ...                ...   
2022-12-23 00:00:00-05:00   2819280000             0.0                0.0   
2022-12-27 00:00:00-05:00   3030300000             0.0                0.0   
2022-12-28 00:00:00-05:00   3083520000             0.0                0.0   
...
2022-12-29 00:00:00-05:00             0.0                0.0  43.295298  
2022-12-30 00:00:00-05:00             0.0                0.0  45.832534  


with the following columns
Index(['^SPX_Open', '^SPX_High', '^SPX_Low', '^SPX_Close', '^SPX_Volume',
       '^SPX_Dividends', '^SPX_Stock Splits', '^SPX_Daily Gain',
       '^SPX_Daily Loss', '^SPX_Average Gain', '^SPX_Average Loss', '^SPX_RSI',
       '^DJI_Open', '^DJI_High', '^DJI_Low', '^DJI_Close', '^DJI_Volume',
       '^DJI_Dividends', '^DJI_Stock Splits', '^DJI_Daily Gain',
       '^DJI_Daily Loss', '^DJI_Average Gain', '^DJI_Average Loss',
       '^DJI_RSI'],
      dtype='object')


Thank you for responding Serge.   Admittedly, I am not a developer, so I am having troubles understanding what is meant by reproducible unless you just want me to add the imports or something.   I figured you just needed the table to see values for verification.   That being said, I looked at your feedback and think I follow your approach.  I think I misunderstood the granularity of the function needed.   I appreciate your help.   I will try implementing tomorrow morning and update how things go.

Confirmed that this did the trick.    Thank you for that.

Returning multiple values from rolling is tricky, so it may be easier to have two functions.  You can control the min_periods and whether you want to you .ge and .le instead of .gt and .lt (ex: greater than or equal to vs greater than).  The first values will be null because there is no prior to compare to, so you can either leave it like that or fill it w/the first known price.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def gain_avg(p):
  return p.loc[p.gt(p.shift())].mean()
def loss_avg(p):
  return p.loc[p.lt(p.shift())].mean()

prices = np.random.randint(10,20,100)
df = pd.DataFrame(prices, columns=['prices'])
df['gain_avg'] = df.prices.rolling(14, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: gain_avg(x))
df['loss_avg'] = df.prices.rolling(14, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: loss_avg(x))

output
   prices  gain_avg   loss_avg
0      17       NaN        NaN
1      19     19.00        NaN
2      17     19.00  17.000000
3      13     19.00  15.000000
4      17     18.00  15.000000
5      13     18.00  14.333333
6      15     17.00  14.333333
7      11     17.00  13.500000
8      18     17.25  13.500000
9      15     17.25  13.800000

